# "Z Notation Bag Membership": What does this represent in math?

Tags: notation

In the glossary for mathematical operators in Unicode<sup>[1](https://symbl.cc/en/unicode/table/#mathematical-operators)</sup>, the last one, u+22FF "⋿", is said to represent "Z Notation Bag Membership".

Looking up "z notation bag membership" gives me this info:

> The symbol "Z Notation Bag Membership" is included in the "Relations" subblock of the "Mathematics Operators" block and was approved as part of Unicode version 3.2 in 2002.

but really all this seems to tell me is that ⋿ is a relation of some sort.

On the Wiktionary<sup>[2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%8B%BF)</sup> for Z Notation Bag Membership,

> 1. (mathematics) A Z notation operator indicating special-defined operation.

although there doesn't seem to be any other info I can find on this, so my question is: Is there any definition of ⋿, or is this a mathematical operator that doesn't really have any meaning?

Comment: Seems like the membership relation for bags, i.e. sets where repeated members are counted.

Comment: Z notation is a ... thing, you can look it up.

Comment: Really, what does *any* mathematical symbol mean?  Nothing until you give it meaning.  I don't see this as a math question.

Comment: It's just a symbol that some authors might define. It looks kind of like $\in$, so you might use it for some kind of membership relation. Math notation isn't universal.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation

Comment: Take a look at section 9.5 of [Using Z: Specification, Refinement, and Proof](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15819/zedbook.pdf), by Jim Woodcock and Jim Davies.

Comment: See also https://www.iso.org/standard/21573.html (I spent too many years of my life working on this: if anyone ever asks you to get involved with a national/international standardisation activity, the only right answer is "NO!".)